# Installing Jre 8 on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jre

So I am trying to install Java Runtime 8 on Ubuntu Linux 14.04. I managed to get OpenJDK 7 using apt-get but I don’t see any JDK 8. I tried to download Oracle's Jre 8 .tar.gz file and I extracted it but it's just a folder. When I do java -version it shows the OpenJDK 7 which I had previously installed, no Jre 8. Please Help!

-----Edit----- 
xenoid I tried that, the OpenJDK 7 was using apt-get and the JRE 8 is a package. I figured out that my python packages messed up during an update and I couldn't install any more packages. I'm Reinstalling Ubuntu. (But now my computer died fully)

Comment: An empty folder? or does it contain a `bin` or a `jre/bin` directory? Did you follow [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/linux_jdk.html#BJFGGEFG)?

Comment: No, It's Not empty. Is does contain a bin folder. And Yes I followed the page

Comment: Here is the jre offline package **[LINK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html)**.

Comment: Take a look here: https://superuser.com/questions/135580/multiple-java-environment-on-the-same-linux-machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have two Java runtimes installed, 1.7 and 1.8. Normally you would use `alternatives` to switch them but that assumes that both have been installed by the standard packaging methods.

The Java8 one is likely not even in your path, but you can start it using a full path:

```
<path-of-installation>/jre/bin/java
```

Answer (score 1):

try with

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
>
> sudo apt update; sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer

Comment: I tried to do that but i didn't work here's what i got:                                  tima@tima-LX6810-01:~$ sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package oracle-java8-installer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'oracle-java8-installer' has no installation candidate

Comment: @DiamondMiner88: Please don’t try to post multi-line comments.  Information regarding what you have tried and what results you got should go into your question, so [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1249099/edit) and put them there.

Answer (score 0):

It's a try, just use the correct java version number, and maybe take a look to the actual folders ?

In the bash:

> ln -s /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java /usr/bin/java
>
> export PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin:$PATH
>
> export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_121

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the latest Java SE SDK version.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/ja...ads/index.html

At the time of writing the filename and version was jdk-7u17-linux-x64.tar.gz

2. Untar the Archive
   tar -xzvf /root/jdk-7u17-linux-x64.tar.gz
   mv jdk1.7.0_17 /opt
   cd /opt/jdk1.7.0_17

3.This step registers the downloaded version of Java as an alternative, and switches it to be used as the default:

update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk1.7.0_17/bin/java 1
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk1.7.0_17/bin/javac 1
update-alternatives --install /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so mozilla-javaplugin.so /opt/jdk1.7.0_17/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so 1
update-alternatives --set java /opt/jdk1.7.0_17/bin/java
update-alternatives --set javac /opt/jdk1.7.0_17/bin/javac
update-alternatives --set mozilla-javaplugin.so /opt/jdk1.7.0_17/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so

4. Test

To check the version of Java you are now running

java -version

To check the browser plugin browse to http://www.java.com/ and click â€œDo I have Java?

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  This question is several years old, and jdk8 wasn't in the Ubuntu repository at that time.  Now it is.  Wouldn't it be preferable to install it that way?